# Sections in Connection string

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Can anyone please help me to understand this block from my `web.config`. What is this?

I have this file in one of the application I am trying to run.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="databaseConnections" type="Components.Database.ConnectionConfigurationHandler, DbHelper" />
</configSections>

<databaseConnections>
<connection name="constr">
  <provider>SQLServer</provider>
  <connectionType>StandardSecurity</connectionType>
  <dataSource>localhost</dataSource>
  <userName>sa</userName>
  <password>sa</password>
  <database>dbName</database>
  <minPoolSize>5</minPoolSize>
  <maxPoolSize>40</maxPoolSize>
</connection>
</databaseConnections>

<appSettings>
    <add key="defaultConnection" value="constr"/>
</appSettings>
```

Please help me to understand this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward to me. The first part tells it how to read the second section by referencing some code. The 2nd part describes a database connection, the 3rd part tells it which database connection to use (the one with the name of "constr").

Comment: Seems to be some kind of custom database component.  I can only find one other reference in google, it must be third party to something you've installed.  The configsection identifies the assembly that contains the code that knows how to parse this section, called `DllHelper` and the namespace is that it lives in which is `Components.Database.ConnectionConfigurationHandler`

Comment: @mason, I want to use local db using `WindowsAuthentication`. In that case how should be the 2nd part ? Is there any guide or reference available, how to use these kind of configuration settings ?

Comment: @RohitGupta - It looks like some kind of custom code.. you will have to find the source of this component and find the source or documentation.  Where did you get the code?  Alternatively, you may be able to decompile it using tools reflector or JustDecompiler.

Comment: @RohitGupta - it looks like it might be a variation of some very old code from the Pro ASP.NET 1.1 book.  Since I have found at least one other reference to this identical web.config (but no reference to the source) it leads me to believe it may have come out of a book like this.  I don't have access to the actual version though...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, That post is from one of the team member who once worked in this application, the bad part is that we are not in touch with him any more.

Comment: @RohitGupta - do you not have the source code to the DbHelper assembly?  If not, you will have to decompile it then, or try and guess what the settings might be, or just rewrite it...

Comment: @RohitGupta - I just noticed you said you wanted to use localdb...  Do you mean the localdb technology?  Or do you mean a local database?  Because if you want to use the localdb technology, I don't see how that bit of configuration would be adequate to configure localdb properly. It would seem that it builds the connection string, and the localdb connection string is a bit different.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, No I do not have the source code I'll have to decompile it. Thanks for helping me out.

And I meant I want to use local database

Comment: It is using a local database (that's what `localhost` is). Unless you mean SQL Server localdb functionality? You could probably just eliminate all the XML your provided from your configuration and replace it with a [standard connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for localdb. Then make sure your application knows to use the provided connection string (see where it makes use of the connection).